# React - Navigation that will smooth scroll to section of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to create a navigation for my single page app that will **smooth scroll** down to the section of the page.

I want to have my navigation at the top of the page with links that when a user clicks, will smooth scroll them down to the section of the page. I'd also like it so if the user goes directly to the link `website.com/about` for example, it will smooth scroll to the section the same way as if you clicked `about` on the navigation component.

I understand how the `react-router-dom` works for routing pages, but I'm confused on how to make it work for this particular purpose.

Could this be achieved with **HashRouter**?

Here's the code I currently have:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="/">Hero</Link>
      <Link to="/">About</Link>
      <Link to="/">Contact</Link>
    </>
  );
}

function Hero() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Hero Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>About Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
}

function Contact() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Contact Section</h1>
    </section>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Hero />
        <About />
        <Contact />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm also providing a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-galileo-8l0l2?file=/src/App.tsx), forks are appretiated! :)

Comment: There's a component called `react-scroll`. I haven't tried it, but it looks like what you are seeking: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Comment: Have you considered using regular anchor tags (`<a href="#about">About</a>` ) and setting page's css `scroll-behavior: smooth`?

Comment: @Jordan there's a `<ScrollView>` in react - why not use that?

Comment: @terrymorse I'd prefer not to use external packages.

Comment: @bsapaka `scroll-behavior` doesn't have the best browser support.

Comment: @RachelGallen I'm pretty sure `ScrollView` is a React Native thing, no?

Comment: @Jordan you'll either have to use an external package or implement it all yourself. React-scroll can help: https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll

Answer (score 14):

What you could do is use an `anchor` tag instead of `Link` from `react-router-dom` and have an `id` on the sections. when the anchor tag is clicked scroll to the corresponding section

```
 <a
  href="/"
  onClick={e => {
  let hero = document.getElementById("hero");
  e.preventDefault();  // Stop Page Reloading
  hero && hero.scrollIntoView();
  }}
  >
  Hero
  </a>

  // Rest of Code 

  function Hero() {
   return (
    <section id="hero">
      <h1>Hero Section</h1>
    </section>
   );
  }
```

and to scroll to a section using a url `path` you would have to get the extract the `path` from `url` and scroll to the section that has that specific `path` as an id

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let url = window.location.href.split("/");
    let target = url[url.length - 1].toLowerCase();
    let element = document.getElementById(target);
    element && element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start"});
  }, []);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-https-jwrj3?file=/src/App.tsx:840-942)

Hope This Helps

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't meet the criteria in my question, you can't go to a section by using the URL, and it doesn't smooth scroll, it just snaps into view.

Comment: You make it smoothly scroll with `scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })`. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: @AlexWayne That fixes the smooth part, but I'm still not able to go directly to the section by using a URL.

Comment: @Jordan i added the smooth effect and improvised a little , just make sure the id of the section is same as the url (i have updated the codesandbox. check it out)

Comment: @AbdullahAbid This is definitely working more like I had hoped. Is there a way of changing the URL after you click on a link? For example if I click on the contact link the URL would updated to `/contact`?

Comment: @jordan https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wood-dtvil?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Jordan you could use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to do that , that would change the url without reloading the page (i have updated the codesandbox), Julians answer  solves it as well.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To allow the link to update in the address bar, use the answer from @Abdullah Abid but change the `<a>` tags to `<link>` and the `href` to `to`.

See my ammendment to Abdullah's Sandbox [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wood-dtvil?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Just add following property to your `index.css` :

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```